# Problem with array index after axios call

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using vue js and axios.

Here is what I am trying to do:

My "outlines" array gets usually between 3 to 9 entries. I would like to run an axios request(runSecondFunction()) on each entry, but only run 1 request at a time(wait for each record to be fetched before initiating another next request, and not all at once. If one of the requests fails, have an error message. Right now as it is, it works but some of the request finish before the others and my index position is wrong in the response.

```
method1(){
   for (const [index, value] of this.splitOutlines.entries()) {
      this.runSecondFunction(value, index);
         }
         }

runSecondFunction(value, index){
       let formData = {
                title: this.blog.value,
                subheading: value
            };
            axios.post('/dashboard/paragraphs', formData).then((response) => {
                this.articles.push({
                    index: index,
                    subheading: response.data.subheading,
                    paragraph: response.data.data.ideas[0],
                });
            }).catch(error => {
                 //
            });
}
```

Any idea how to do this please?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're really adamant about these not running concurrently, then you'll have to do one of two things. You can make `method1` call an `async` function and throw a try catch around it while composing an new array and returning or setting that somewhere else. e.g.

```js
method1(){
   (async function () {
     const requests = []
     for (const [index, value] of this.splitOutlines.entries()) {
       try {
         const res = await this.runSecondFunction(value, index);
         requests.push(res)
       } catch (e) {
         requests.push(e)
       }
     }
    return requests
    )().then(reqs => {
       // do other stuff with the completed requests.
    })

}
```

This should guarantee the order of the requests is respected and only one will be run at a time.

Otherwise, you'll have to do a sort of recursive implementation in the `.then` method.

EDIT::

I forgot to mention that in your `runSecondFunction` method, you need to return the promise, so it should look like this:

```js
runSecondFunction(value, index){
    let formData = {
        title: this.blog.value,
        subheading: value
    };
    return axios.post('/dashboard/paragraphs', formData)

}
```

This way, the `await` from `mehtod1` will assign the article to what I called `res` (You can of course manipulate this data any way you need).

But don't handle the error within `runSecondFunction` if you want them to be present in the array.

Comment: Thank you so much, I am going to give it a shot today with the above code and post back :-)

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be to push an error object into the array if there's an error.

```
axios.post('/dashboard/paragraphs', formData).then((response) => {
    this.articles.push({
        index: index,
        subheading: response.data.subheading,
        paragraph: response.data.data.ideas[0],
    });
}).catch(error => {
    this.articles.push({ error });
});
```

Or you could change the articles to be a plain object instead of an array, and assign to properties of the object instead of pushing.

```
axios.post('/dashboard/paragraphs', formData).then((response) => {
    this.articles[index] = {
        index: index,
        subheading: response.data.subheading,
        paragraph: response.data.data.ideas[0],
    }
}).catch(error => {
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't think this will guarantee the order of the requests.

Comment: It will if you run them sequentially, like you said - just await each call.

Comment: The problem is that some of them may finish after 2 seconds, others 10 seconds. I am currently trying to do it via Laravel instead(php) as I struggle with JS for this.

Comment: No matter how long it takes each to resolve, it should be trivially to wait for them to do so sequentially - like I said, just `await` each of the Promises so that they have to finish completely before the next one starts. `await axios.post(...`, and also `await this.runSecondFunction(`